# Weird Gap Between Views in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react naive and am trying to place two views one under the other but when I try doing this there is a big gap between the views as shown below.

[image: Gap]

This anyway to be able to fix this or do I need to use flatlist?

Here is my code.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", height: 130 }}>
        <View style={styles.IconImage}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              Linking.openURL("http://facebook.com/")
            }
          >
            <FontAwesome
              name="location-arrow"
              size={40}
              color={"#E8AA65"}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 50, paddingLeft: 40 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Find Us</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", height: 130 }}>
        <View style={styles.IconImage}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              Linking.openURL("http://facebook.com/")
            }
          >
            <Icon
              name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-settings" : "md-settings"}
              size={40}
              color={"#E8AA65"}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 50, paddingLeft: 40 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Settings</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     IconImage: {
       paddingTop: 40,
       paddingLeft: 40,
     },  
   });
```

Comment: It's not a perfect tool for these issues, but consider using the inspector inside [react native debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger), on the iOS emulator you can toggle it via `⌘`+`i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by providing `flex:1` in your main view.

**Output without `flex:1`:**

[image: Output]

The remaining offset is caused by your `height` together with your `padding` values.

**Demo:**

I've created a snack where you can play around with it:

https://snack.expo.io/rkUKpLUUU